# Modulo Mysql executando script errado - Node Js

Tags: node.js, express.js

Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema simples de persistência de clientes, produtos e venda. Fiz uma *API* usando o express e o módulo do *MySQL*, porém algo estranho etá ocorrendo e eu realmente não tenho ideia do que possa ser:

Eu possuo essa rota:

```
 app.post("/cliente/salvar", function(request, response){

    let cliente = request.body;

    let connection = dbConnection();

    if(cliente.id){
        clienteFactoryDAO.alterarCliente(connection, cliente, function(erro, result){
            response.send(result);
            if(erro != null) console.log(erro);
            connection.end();
        });
    }else{
        clienteFactoryDAO.salvarCliente(connection, cliente, function(erro, result){
            response.send(result);
            if(erro != null) console.log(erro);
            connection.end();
        });
    }

});
```

Note que a mesma faz referência a um método do módulo *clienteFactoryDAO*, código desse método está assim:

```
this.salvarCliente = function(connection, objeto, callback){

    let sqlEndereco = utilCliente.createSaveAdressQuery(objeto.endereco);

    console.log(sqlEndereco);

    connection.query(sqlEndereco, function (error, results){
        if(error) throw error;
        objeto.id_endereco = results.insertId;

        //Depois que salva o endereco, usa-se o id persistido e salva-se o cliente
        let sql =  utilCliente.createSaveQuery(objeto);
        console.log(sql);
        connection.query(sql, callback);
    })

}
```

Notem que eu fecho a conexão no segundo `connection.query`, dentro do *callback*, isso porque eu não posso fechar antes, visto que preciso primeiro salvar o endereço para aquele cliente e depois, salvar o cliente.

Pois bem, o erro: O endpoint acessado é o correto mas no momento que executa-se o `connection.query()`, ele executa a query de inserção do produto, eu não tenho ideia do porquê! Eu já li a documentação inteira do módulo *MySQL* no *GitHub* e, ainda não obtive sucesso em descobrir! Será que estou fechando conexão direito? Já tentei usar o método *destroy* e nada!

Obrigado desde já e peço desculpas se não fui claro o suficiente em minha dúvida

Comment: Não precisa fechar a conexão manualmente em cada requisição. Você pode criá-la ao iniciar a aplicação, exportá-la e reutilizá-la em suas rotas.

Comment: @ruanmartinelli, você acredita que seja a conexão a causa do problema?

Comment: Não saberia dizer com certeza. Falei mais como uma dica, abrir uma nova conexão toda vez que for consultar o banco é uma operação relativamente custosa.